# When to use JSF Component libraries tags?

Tags: jsf, components

I know the simple answer to this question is "if the component you need is not defined in JSF tag library you can use a component library". What about simple components like buttons, checkboxes, etc? If I am already using a component library for other components, should I also use this component library's tags or JSF's? What are the pros/cons of both approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's logical: if you don't need the additional features of a component library's component on top of a standard component such as different look'n'feel, enhanced ajax support and/or other fanciness, then you can just keep using the standard component.

Comment: the project that I took over consists of lots of components from a component library which already exists in JSF tags. Should I then convert them to JSF tags? Is there any disadvantage of keeping them?

Comment: In fact, there should not really be disadvangages of keeping them. But if you (or at least, the business/functional requirements) don't need the enhancements the component library provides over the standard components, then you don't necessarily **need** the component library's component. However, I checked your question history and your case is a bit different: you seem to be using Woodstock which is a dead and abandoned component library. It **definitely** needs replacement.

Comment: thanks for your deep investigation :) and reccommendation. By the way, I couldn't find a solution to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118908/replacing-the-behavior-of-js-alert-box-in-jsf-2-0-with-what 
You were answering it, then you deleted your answer. Did you promised not answer any question related to Woodstock? :)

Comment: I do not use Woodstock so I am not aware of any "side-effects" it may have which would void my answers. I only post answers of which I am 99.9% certain that it is valid.

Comment: I understand. But I also tried it without Woodstock components and it is still giving the same error..

Comment: I am still trying to find a way to solve this problem. I asked another question related to a parallel solution. Would you be kind enough to take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183353/jsf-lifecycle-realated Thanks in advance.