# How to validate an empty field in action method?

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

I have an input field and a button. I want to check if the `textinput` is valid before executing the button action. If it is valid I will render a response message. I have a code like this:

```
public void submitReportRequest() {
    if(nameField!=null){
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        submitted=true;
    }
    if(nameField == null){
        System.out.println("report name is null!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

but from the console I just get:

```
[#|2011-11-18T15:22:49.931+0200|INFO|glassfishv3.0|null|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|#]
```

when the `nameField` is empty, I receive nothing in the console just page is re-rendered with the validation message of `nameField`. I know from the JSF life cycle if the validation phase fails then it jumps directly to the render response phase and button action is never reached. But how can I achieve my objective in this case?

Comment: You are not using JSR303 Bean Validation at all. So I removed the `[bean-validation]` tag. To learn what Bean Validation really is, read [our wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bean-validation/info) and [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty submitted values default to empty strings, not `null`. Instead, you need to check if the string is empty by [`String#isEmpty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29):

```
if (nameField.isEmpty()) {
    // Name field is empty.
} else {
    // Name field is not empty.
}
```

You perhaps want to cover blank spaces as well. In that case, add `trim()`:

```
if (nameField.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // Name field is empty or contained spaces only.
} else {
    // Name field is not empty and did not contain spaces only.
}
```

Note that the `String#isEmpty()` is introduced in Java 1.6. If you're still on Java 1.5 or older for some reason, then you need to check [`String#length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) instead.

```
if (nameField.length() == 0) {
    // Name field is empty.
} else {
    // Name field is not empty.
}
```

However, that's not the normal way of required field validation. You should put the `required="true"` attribute on the input field instead.

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" required="true" />
<h:message for="name" />
```

This way JSF will validate it by itself and display the appropriate message and will skip the action method invocation.

#### See also:

- [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually the original code was required="true" but because I want to do some action according to this fields validation I wanted to write a separated validation method. Writing separate validation method solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. For custom validation you'd have used a `Validator` for this.

Comment: By the way, I already read your valuable article about JSF lifecycles. Thanks for that also :)

Comment: I just saw your edits. Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer.